# How to create two columns in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two columns like a news paper that will be side by side on my webpage. It is basic html. Each column starts with an h1 tag and then the body of the column is a p tag with a few sentences.  What css stylers would be best to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Specially you can use multi column for newspaper style.

```css
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

The CSS3 multi-column layout allows easy definition of multiple columns of text - just like in newspapers